# Java Object Memory Management

Tags: java-8

I'm concerned about the methods that show how much memory space an object is allocating I know these methods are in the Runtime class but they don't seem to appear on my IDE are they in a different class in Java 8? My Java version is 1.8.0._51.

Comment: If you mean things like `freeMemory` and `maxMemory`, no they have not moved.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA I only see the getRuntime method in the Runtime class.

Comment: To invoke non-`static` methods, you need an object of that class which is exactly what `getRuntime()` delivers. So you may invoke `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` or you store the result of `getRuntime()` in a local variable if you want to invoke mutliple methods on it.

Comment: Thanks Holger! I just noticed that the Runtime class is a singleton because of the private constructor this makes more sense now.